# Windows Store apps not displaying after the recent update

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-store-app

My Windows 8.1 Pro just got an update recently this month of November 2014 and today, I just noticed that none of Windows Store apps are not displaying at all.

Here's the youtube video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ck2g6riUgmQ

Here's my PC specs
[image]

Comment: First step;  Uninstall the most recent updates for the time being to verify the Modern UI applications work if they are removed

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2013/10/11/what-to-do-if-your-windows-8-modern-app-fails-to-start.aspx